# Ваш никнейм

Tags: имена-собственные

Дорогие форумчане! Чем вы руководствовались, выбирая себе "сетевое имя"? Что оно обозначает?  Вопрос личный, если за вашим ником кроется "страааашная таааайна", то можете ее не раскрывать:).

У меня все просто.  Решила оставить свое имя, форма "домашняя" (просто нравится, когда меня так называют, особенно близкие).  Уменьшительно-ласкательный суффикс добавляет нежность в обращении и несерьезность, легкомысленность (т.е. мои ответы не претендуют на истину в последней инстанции)

Comment: Спасибо большое всем за ответы! Надеюсь, никто не обидится, если я оставлю за собой право не выбирать лучший ответ, т.к. ценю открытость и выдумку каждого из вас!

Answer (score 8):

В моём случае основных причин для никнейма 3:

1. Традиция. Ещё лет в 12 придумал каламбур Марк Из-маркиз. Ник хорошо подходил к моим любимым жанрам компьютерных игр, был запоминающимся и коротким. Варианты ника - Mark Is, Марк_Из, Mark_Is, MarkIs.
2. Труднопроизносимость настоящего имени. Имя у меня - Владислав, что в сокращении даёт Влад. Звонкий согласный на конце имени произнести хочется, но затруднительно. В реале имя произносят по разному, вплоть до Владя и Слава, но на просторах интернета можно и облегчить собеседнику задачу, позволив называть себя Марком или Марк Изом.
3. Анонимность. В некоторых случаях гораздо удобней, когда твоё настоящее имя неизвестно сетевым собеседникам.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!   

Каламбур хороший :). 

Я свое имя переводила на разные языки. Понравилось на итальянском - Speranzа  и на испанском -Еsperanza. Иногда пользуюсь. Но многие z читают как [з],  а нужно [ц].

Answer (score 7):

Мой ник говорит сам за себя. Я учусь в школе. Это раз . У меня нет таких знаний, как у вас. Даже если я школу закончу. Это два.  А читать интересно.

Comment: Все участники форума тоже были когда-то школьниками, так что у кого-то всё впереди :)

Answer (score 7):

А у меня — персонаж одного из моих любимых аниме. Он по характеру похож на меня. Я вообще к никам отношусь очень серьезно и никогда не беру просто потому, что слово понравилось. Мой ник для меня всегда — альтер эго.

Comment: Звучит интересно. А я пока не знаю, на кого я по характеру похожа.

Comment: Думаю, такая вещь обязательно придет сама. А может, Вы ни на кого не похожи, что еще лучше!

Answer (score 5):

Вообще-то ников у меня в Сети много, хороших и разных.
А насчет нынешнего...

Есть на свете очень милые скотики,
Что не пьют, не глотают наркотики,
И живут безо всякой экзотики,
А название им - бегемотики.

Не такие уж они толстокожие,
Не такие уж они глупорожие,
Просто обижают их прохожие
Потому, что на них непохожие.

Comment: Очень симпатичное стихотворение! Я тоже люблю бегемотиков с киндерсюрпризовского детства.   

Еще стойкая ассоциация с "Мастером..."

Comment: Боже... С булгаковским? Не, не смею даже подумать.
Хотя вы мне напомнили. Давно собирался еще раз подумать, что это за никчемная фигура в заголовке романа и чем он так мил МАБу...

Comment: Я про Бегемота :))))) Но и мастерство не отрицаю

Comment: Ааааа... С котом. Не, это уже пройденный этап. Хотя мой ник "Чеширский Бегемот" был данью и ему. 
Но сейчас я какой-то другой Бегемот. Не кошкообразный.

Comment: В борьбе котов и бегемотов победил сильнейший :). 

Тоже интересный ник, 2 характера в одном :)

Comment: Самое интересное, что это вполне соответвстует действительности. 
Непутевый увалень Бегемот пересилил хитрюгу-кота. 

Наши ники - это не то, что мы из себя представляем, а то, чем мы хотим быть. 
Психологи знают этот парадокс. 
Чтобы понравиться мужчине, надо видеть его таким, каким он сам себя видит.
Чтобы добиться успеха у женщины, надо любить её такой, какой она *хочет* казаться.

Comment: Недавно в соц.сети попалась информация про аватарки: почему люди выбирают те или иные. Тоже интересно, отражение внутреннего мира и/или желание казаться кем-то.

О котах. Часто любвеобильных мужчин называю "котами мартовскими".

Comment: Был этот  ник у меня ;)

Answer (score 5):

Ну, я в некотором роде и правда пишу книги и не только. Но вот относиться к себе серьезно — это последнее дело. Поэтому ник взят с долей самоиронии (тем более, что я, как и тот чукча из всем известного анекдота, делаю невероятное количество опечаток: "Чукча — не читатель, чукча — писатель" ) ))))

Comment: У меня рекордсмен по опечаткам - автокорректор. Пишешь одно слово, а он упорно вставляет то, что считает нужным. Можно сказать, что живет своей жизнью. Иногда получаются такие перлы. Просто смех.

Comment: Здорово! Может, поделитесь?)))  
Вообще, чувствую, надо нам где-то не только вопросы задавать, а еще обмениваться всякими подобными коллекциями и обсуждать вопросы, которые в рамки этого форума не вписываются.

Comment: Я специально не собираю, а идея хорошая! Если что-то вспомню, обязательно напишу. Я, если вижу, исправляю.   

Я стала собирать детские "перлы". Записываю, когда есть время.

Comment: Кстати, теперь тут есть возможность писать "исследования", то есть развернутые сообщения не в виде вопросов. Можно будет начать с этого.

Comment: Отличная идея! Надо будет подумать, что написать.

Answer (score 3):

Вообще, у меня и правда есть некоторая доля аристократических кровей. И еще больше шляхетского гонора :)))

Comment: Похоже на "Нобель".  Буду знать :)